# Handling terms and conditions at Azure AD B2C registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm implementing Azure AD B2C in my public facing app and with this approach, new user registration is essentially taking place "outside" of my app on Azure.

How can I enforce users agreeing to my terms and conditions? In other words, I'd like there to be a checkbox and it must be mandatory for users to check it to proceed with the registration process. If the user doesn't check the checkbox, registration should not take place.

I understand through UI customization I can change the appearance of the registration page and there can be a highlighted statement that reads:

> By clicking Register, you're agreeing to our terms and conditions.

I think it would be better if there was a mandatory checkbox though. Is this doable with Azure AD B2C?

UPDATE:
In Step 5, I'm not seeing "Custom Attributes" -- here's the screen shot:
[image]

UPDATE 2:
Not allowing me to save after uploading `json` file for override.
[image]

Comment: It was done in the WingTip demo https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net, not sure how though.  Source code: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr) that prompts for the end-user agreement.

E.g. Create a custom attribute called `AgreedToTermsAndConditions` of type `String`.

**For built-in policies**

To display this custom attribute as a checkbox that must be checked during sign-up:

1. In the Azure portal, open **Azure AD B2C** and then select **Sign-up or sign-in policies**.
2. In **Sign-up or sign-in policies**, select the sign-up or sign-in policy.
3. For the selected policy, select **Edit**.
4. In **Edit policy**, select **Sign-up attributes**.
5. In **Select sign-up attributes**, select the custom attribute and then select **OK**.
6. In **Edit policy**, select **Page UI customization**.
7. In **Page UI customization**, select **Local account sign-up page**.
8. In **Local account sign-up page**, select the sign-up attribute.
9. In **Edit attribute**, select **No** for **Optional** and **CheckboxMultiSelect** for **User input type** and then select **OK**.
10. In **Local account sign-up page**, select **OK**.
11. Repeat steps 7-10 for **Social account sign-up page**.
12. In **Page UI customization**, select **OK**.
13. In **Edit policy**, select **Save**.
14. In **Edit policy**, select **Language customization**.
15. In **Language customization**, select **Enable language customization** if it isn't already enabled.
16. In **Language customization**, select the default language.
17. For the selected language, expand **Local account sign-up page** and upload a resource file such as the following example.
18. Repeat step 16 for **Social account sign-up page**.
19. Repeat steps 16-18 for other enabled languages.

An example of the resource file:

```
{
  "LocalizedCollections": [
    {
      "ElementType": "ClaimType",
      "ElementId": "extension_AgreedToTermsAndConditions",
      "TargetCollection": "Restriction",
      "Override": true,
      "Items": [
        {
          "Name": "I agree to your terms and conditions",
          "Value": "True"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(Phew!)

You can also set the item value to a date string (e.g. "2018-04-01") or a version string (e.g. "v1") if you are wanting to store the date or version of the terms and conditions.

**For custom policies**

*Updated on 23 May 2018*

The [Manage user access in Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-access#capture-terms-of-use-agreement) article describes how you can prompt for the end-user agreement during sign-up and, subsequently, during sign-in if the end user hasn't accepted the latest or new terms and conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer but at Step 5, I'm not seeing custom attributes -- see screen shot under UPDATE in original post.

Comment: Did you create the custom attribute (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr#create-a-custom-attribute)?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that rather important step!!! Almost done but kind of stuck on step 17. I uploaded the `json` file but save is grayed out. I only have local account login, no social. Any idea why it's not allowing me to save it?

Comment: Uploaded a screen shot in original post under UPDATE 2

Comment: You mightn't have to select Save at step 17.

Comment: You're exactly right! There's no need to save at step 17. I was able to get the checkbox in the form but looks like it doesn't accept HTML for the label so "Terms and conditions" are not clickable. I guess that has to be done by creating a custom UI for the whole page. Is that right? Chris, I can't thank you enough. You've been helping me with this all along the way  and I really appreciate your help. This is NOT precisely intuitive stuff!!!

Comment: @Sam Thank you for that. I have removed the "save" step from the above answer. You are right, the attribute labels can't include any HTML content, so you must show a Ts&Cs link or the Ts&Cs text using a custom page UI. Go to [the WoodGrove Groceries app](https://woodgrovegroceriesb2c.azurewebsites.net/Account/LogIn), select **Sign in with your personal account**, and then select **Sign up now** for an example of this.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help and absolutely fantastic instructions -- better than Microsoft Docs!

Comment: Here is the Template for the UI https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/master/Templates/src/local_account_registration_1.html

Comment: This example covers accepting terms and conditions, have you tried using extension_termsOfUseConsentDateTime and extension_termsOfUseConsentVersion in user flow as per learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/… –